# Unable to chain iterators into a new iterator that isn't iterable

Tags: javascript

I've got two iterators that may or may not be iterable. If they were both guaranteed to be iterable, I could probably use an array and call `.values()` to get another iterable iterator:

```js
[...iter1, ...iter2].values(); // simple :)
```

However, I'm struggling to find a way to chain them together if they aren't iterable.
I considered using a generator function, but that would return a *generator* and not an *iterator*. Ideally, the returned iterator should also not be iterable.

This returns an iterable iterator and only works for iterable iterators:

```js
const iter1 = [1, 2, 3].values();
const iter2 = [4, 5, 6].values();

console.log([...[...iter1, ...iter2].values()]);
```

This works for iterators that aren't iterable but instead returns a generator:

```js
const iter1 = [1, 2, 3].values();
const iter2 = [4, 5, 6].values();

console.log([...(function* () {
  let item;
  while (!(item = iter1.next()).done) yield item.value;
  while (!(item = iter2.next()).done) yield item.value;
})()]);
```

So how would I take two iterators and chain them together to create a new iterator?

---

Maybe an XY problem; I'm concerned about iterability since TypeScript has separate interfaces: Iterator and IterableIterator. Is it implying that you can create an iterator that isn't iterable, or are all iterators in JavaScript iterable, and TypeScript is just being weird?

Comment: This snippet may be useful `[].concat(iter1, iter2).values()`

Comment: @Wazeed That'll give me an iterator of iterators. If you've got a way to "flatten" them after, then that's a potential answer. Ideally, the returned iterator shouldn't be iterable as well (don't know if it's even possible for an iterator to not be iterable in JavaScript yet...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll post the obvious answer that despite being old-fashioned and baroque, seems to fit the requirements:

```js
class ConsIterable{
    constructor(...iterators){
        this.iterators = iterators;
        this.current = 0;
    }
    next(){
        let result;
        do{
            result = this.iterators[this.current].next();
            if(result.done){
                this.current++;
            }
        }while(result.done && this.current < this.iterators.length);
        return result;
    }
}

const iter1 = [1, 2, 3].values();
const iter2 = [4, 5, 6].values();

const chained_iterable = new ConsIterable(iter1, iter2);
let nxt;
do{
    nxt = chained_iterable.next();
    console.log(nxt);
}while(!nxt.done)
```

Answer (score 1):

An elegant solution, using [iter-ops](https://github.com/vitaly-t/iter-ops), which can concatenate both iterables and iterators:

```
import {pipe, concat} from 'iter-ops';

const iter1 = [1, 2, 3].values(); // test iterator 1
const iter2 = [4, 5, 6].values(); // test iterator 2

const i = pipe([], concat(iter1, iter2)); //=> IterableIterator<number>

console.log(...i); //=> 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

To test it with proper `Iterator`-only (non-iterable) inputs, let's create a helper below, and replace our `iter1` and `iter2` inputs:

```
function createIterator(values: number[]): Iterator<number> {
    let index = 0;
    return {
        next() {
            if (index < values.length) {
                return {value: values[index++], done: false};
            }
            return {value: undefined, done: true}
        }
    };
}

const iter1 = createIterator([1, 2, 3]); //=> Iterator<number>
const iter2 = createIterator([4, 5, 6]); //=> Iterator<number>
```

Concatenating the updated `iter1` and `iter2` will produce the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally the returned iterator shouldn't be iterable as well, but if we mix the two possibilities mentioned in the post, we'll achieve:

```
const iter1 = [1, 2, 3].values();
const iter2 = [4, 5, 6].values();

const result = [];
let item;
while (!(item = iter1.next()).done) result.push(item.value);
while (!(item = iter2.next()).done) result.push(item.value);

const chained = result.values(); // but still iterable
```

However the returned iterator is still iterable. Honestly, I don't even know if you can even have an iterator that isn't iterable in JavaScript. I was under the impression that you could since TypeScript provides separate interfaces for them.

Deleting (with `delete` keyword) `@@iterator` also doesn't seem to work (?).

Comment: Why not just hide `@@iterator` - `const chained_iterable = result.values(), chained = {next: chained_iterable.next.bind(chained_iterable)}`?